# Safari flickers when image tag is replaced by the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Our Safari/Mac users report flickering of image on a page segment which is periodically updated by AJAX call. We are not able to reproduce the behavior in Chrome/Firefox/IE on Win and Linux, not even Chrome on Mac.

We do not have a Mac available for development, so I can only sometimes ask a friend to check it for me. I prepared a simplified test case: https://jsfiddle.net/tgb1jaog/1/

We use IMG element which is inside the refreshed div, but is always the same and on the same position for given page and it blinks on each refresh when viewed in Safari - on real page and on jsfiddle too (first div).

I tried to change it to CSS background set by STYLE on DIV in place of the original IMG, that seems to work fine on jsfiddle (second div), but blinks the same way on our real page.

I am going to try to define the background in external css and give the div only a class (jsfiddle third div), but as the test case behavior differs I am not sure it will help.

All those work well using different browser.

Is it some kind of a bug in Safari (I was not able to find any reference)? Or are there some ways how to make Safari work as others?

```js
function replace(id, data) {
    $("#" + id).empty();
    $("#" + id).append($.trim(data));
    $("#" + id).hide();
    $("#" + id).show()
}
function d1() {
    replace("d1", '<img src="https://live.victoriatip.cz/images/baseball-header.jpg" width="797" height="69" />');
}
function d2() {
    replace("d2", '<div style="background: url(https://live.victoriatip.cz/images/baseball-header.jpg); width: 797px; height: 69px;"></div>');
}
function d3() {
    replace("d3", '<div class="b"></div>');
}
setInterval(d1, 2000);
setInterval(d2, 2500);
setInterval(d3, 3000);
```

```css
#d3 .b {
    background: url("https://live.victoriatip.cz/images/baseball-header.jpg");
    width: 797px;
    height: 69px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix" id="d1"></div>
<div class="clearfix" id="d2"></div>
<div class="clearfix" id="d3"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try to set a width and height on the `<img>` tag? If you don't set a predefined width and height the browser might flicker from time to time when reloading because of the unknown measurements.

Comment: @sqe it is set in real and in the fiddle/snippet: --width="797" height="69"-- and it is the same size as the image has, so no resizing has to be done.

Comment: You can build in a test to see if the new content is the same as the current one...

Comment: @MrLister I cannot, some other parts of the "section" will change, and the system is sending updated html of entire section instead of say json with numbers to change (would like to change that in the future but cannot do that now)

Comment: Urg, I'm having the exact same issue. Did you end up figuring out a solution?

Comment: @Tama did you check the fiddle/snippet and does it do the same? I resolved it by using the version #3 - only a class name/id on the element and proper css definitions in external file - that seems to work ok. I think maybe some kind of garbage collection is kicking in too early and/or some part of changes is processed in different thread so after the change we are "allowed" to see partial results. But the inconsistent handling of case #2 (fiddle works ok, our version did not, one difference is amount of html code) is the only pointer I have about possible reason.

Comment: Hey @jkavalik think I've solved it, check the answer I've just added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out Safari will re-request an image if the cache has expired, even if it's already in memory (unlike Chrome, Firefox etc). If you look at the Safari debug tools while your jsfiddle is running you'll see the server requests piling up (they return a 304 but it's enough to cause the flicker).

This image in your jsfiddle example: `https://live.victoriatip.cz/images/baseball-header.jpg` is set to expire straight away - `Expires: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 14:26:53 GMT`.

If you tweak your cache headers the problem should go away.

Here's an updated jsfiddle with a google image that caches: https://jsfiddle.net/tgb1jaog/2/.